# combobox index set to -1 when changing it s text

Tags: c#, combobox

in a combobox i have the names of clients and 3 textboxs for there email address and tel num and by clicking on a button we  modifie there informations in a datatable changing the 3 textboxs values get applied on the datatable but changing the name which is displayed on the combobox set the combobox selected index to -1 so the values don't change in dtable

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        MessageBox.Show("done");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Clients SET Name = '"+comboBox1.Text.ToString()+"', Email= '"+textBox1.Text.ToString() + "',Address='"+textBox2.Text.ToString() + "',Number='"+textBox3.Text.ToString() + "' WHERE ID="+comboBox1.SelectedIndex+";", cn);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dr[1] = comboBox1.Text;
        dr[2] = textBox1.Text;
        dr[3] = textBox2.Text;
        dr[4] = textBox3.Text;


    }
```

so whenever i modifie in the comboBox an error say that there is no line at position -1

ps : sorry for my EN :)

ps:: the sql is fine no need to use sql tag

Comment: FWIW, your *SQL* is **not** fine, and a big nasty [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack waiting to happen

Comment: it s just for school i m not running a business here

Comment: Also `so whenever i modifie in the comboBox` your are showing no modifications in your code.. In short if this is happening, the logical solution is before you modify your `comboBox` keep your `SelectedIndex` and re-Select afterwards

Comment: by modifing i meant changing the text not the index